# Big black rectangle

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, repair

A big black rectangle is slowly overtaking the screen on my macbook.  It is all frozen can't do anything.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it remain after a reboot? Is it visible in a screenshot (Shift-Cmd-3)?

Comment: It's possible that you have a dying GPU–some older MacBook Pros had a problem with that. What MacBook do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Hold the power button to shut off the Mac.

When you restart it, hold the option key and see if the graphics glitch is present in the startup screen where you choose which OS to boot.

It's probably the software that got stuck, so it won't likely be there when you restart - but it's good to note where the rectangle was / take a photo in case it returns.